# XPATH Expression fails in JQuery

Tags: jquery, xpath

I ran into a problem while trying to parse an XML string returned from an Ajax Call. The structure of the XML is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <endPointDefs>
 <endPointDef>
  <useCaseId>USER_LOGIN</useCaseId>
  <endPointUrl>/core.authenticate.do</endPointUrl>
  <endPointUrlParams>
   <endPointUrlParam name="MsgFormat">
    <urlParamType>SYSTEM_DEFINED</urlParamType>
    <urlParamValueSystemDefined>USER_LOGIN</urlParamValueSystemDefined>
   </endPointUrlParam>
   <endPointUrlParam name="userId">
    <urlParamType>USER_PROVIDED</urlParamType>
   </endPointUrlParam>
   <endPointUrlParam name="password">
    <urlParamType>USER_PROVIDED</urlParamType>
   </endPointUrlParam>
   <endPointUrlParam name="language">
    <urlParamType>USER_PROVIDED</urlParamType>
   </endPointUrlParam>
  </endPointUrlParams>
 </endPointDef>
</endPointDefs>
```

However, I need the value for the  tag for the useCaseId USER_LOGIN. A typical XPATH expression for this should like this:

```
/endPointDefs/endPointDef[useCaseId='USER_LOGIN']/endPointUrl
```

I stored the response from the ajax call in a javascript variable as follows:

```
var endPointDefs=null;
```

This variable is populated from an Ajax Call as follows:

```
    $.ajax(
   {
    type:"POST",
    url: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/data/EndPointDefs.xml",
    dataType:"XML",
    success:function(data){
          //alert("End Points Loaded: " + data);
          endPointDefs=data;
        },
      error: function() {
         alert('an error occurred! which trying to fetch the end point definitions');
          }  
   }
    );
```

I tried to execute the XPATH query using JQuery as follows:

```
    $("endPointDefs/endPointDef[useCaseId='USER_LOGIN']/endPointUrl",endPointDefs).each(function(){
   $('#txtUseCase').val('USER_LOGIN');
   $('#txtEntryPointURL').val($(this).text());

  })
```

This is a modified version of what was show here:
http://www.compoc.com/tuts/

Though, an alternative approach would be to iterate over all the endPointDef elements and inspect the value of the useCaseId and if it matches my string [USER_LOGIN], then, set the text in the text box. But, a more elegant approach would be to use an XPATH expression indicated above, which would give me the desired results in one shot.

I tried many combinations and nothing seems to work. Does JQuery support this kind of XPath queries? If so, can somebody please tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are 2 things going on here: first, jQuery uses `>` as the direct-child selector, so you should use this instead of `/`. Second, you are using the endPointDefs xml as a context, which means that when jQuery starts looking for elements, it is already "in" the `<endPointDefs>` tag. In this tag, there are no `<endPointDefs>` tags, so it doesn't find any.

EDIT: also, to check for text in a tag, use the `:contains()` selector.

EDIT 2: Ah, now I see the `endPointUrl` is next to the `useCaseId`, not inside it.

The correct selector, I think, would be:

```
$("endPointDef>useCaseId:contains('USER_LOGIN')+endPointUrl",endPointDefs)
```

Comment: No. It doesn't work. I guess the [] are for selecting attributes and not for tag values. In the case of XPATH, for attribute we use the [@attr=value]  syntax.

Comment: Are you sure? I have an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cGuLg/ (it `alert`s the number of found elements, which is 1. Maybe you should use `$(endPointDefs)` instead of just `endPointDefs`?

Comment: This works $("endPointDef>useCaseId:contains('USER_LOGIN')+endPointUrl",endPointDefs) 

Thanks for your time. I think I have to start learning css selectors. :)

Comment: There seems to be an issue with IE 7. The above selector works in FF but not in IE 7.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't use XPath, but CSS-like selectors.  Given that you only have one `endPointUrl` element, I would think you could use the following selector:

```
$("endPointUrl",endPointDefs)
```

---

Since you indicate that there can be more than one `endPointUrl` tag, I'd go for the following, which is more natural jQuery:

```
$('useCaseId', endPointDefs).filter(function(){
    return $.text(this) == 'USER_LOGIN';
}).next();
```

Comment: In fact, I have couple of other endPointUrl definitions. What is shown is just a sample of the XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#XPath_Selectors

> Supported Predicates
>
> 1. **[@foo]** Has an attribute of foo
>
>    ```
>     $("//input[@checked]")
>    ```
> 2. **[@foo='test']** Attribute foo is equal to test
>
>    ```
>     $("//a[@ref='nofollow']")
>    ```
> 3. **[Nodelist]** Element contains a node list, for example:
>
>    ```
>     $("//div[p]")
>     $("//div[p/a]")
>    ```

Comment: That's the API for 1.1.2, and is very, very outdated. [Here is the current API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).